# react native Webview doesn't render html while import the file from local

Tags: react-native

When I directly enter the html string or online line inside the it perfectly reder the html. Working code is below

```
    <WebView 
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{
      html: `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Cool Effects with Marquees</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is Test</h1>
</body>
</html>` }}/>
```

But if load the .html file from local path, it is render as plain text.

```
<WebView
 originWhitelist={['*']}
 source={require('./../../disc/html/1.html')}
 startInLoadingState={true}
 />
```

[image]

Comment: any solution that worked?